# Can't access React Native App object's property from inside method using this

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is being tested on Android using expo. The property `randomNumber` is can be read and written to by the `render()` method (I have tested with an alert and set operation right before the return statement), but for some reason it is undefined and can neither be read or set in the method `newNumber()`.

The "Old" and "Set" alerts display `undefined`, the "New" alert displays a random number as expected. Sometimes an alert doesn't show. I'm assuming that it's just getting closed quickly from a prolonged touch. The alerts seem to be asynchronous and display in random order but the number displayed in the app never changes so I'm pretty sure that is not the issue. This might be obvious but I'm baffled

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Button, View, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    randomNumber = 9;

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{this.randomNumber}</Text>
                <Button onPress={this.newNumber} title='New Random Number'/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    newNumber() {
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
        Alert.alert('Old: ' + this.randomNumber);
        Alert.alert('New: ' + number);
        this.randomNumber = number;
        Alert.alert('Set: ' + this.randomNumber);

    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change instance variable your view did not reload. you must use state vari to reload view.

Example:

```
constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = { randomNumber:9 };
}

 render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.randomNumber}</Text>
            <Button onPress={this.newNumber.bind(this)} title='New Random Number'/>
        </View>
    );
}

 newNumber() {
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
        Alert.alert('Old: ' + this.randomNumber);
        Alert.alert('New: ' + number);
        this.setState({randomNumber: number});
        Alert.alert('Set: ' + number);
  }
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I forgot about state. The code you provided doesn't work though. I get the error: 

undefined is not a function (evaluation 'this.setState({randomNumber: number})')

Comment: Yeah that works. Thanks. I've also tried `onPress={()=>this.newNumber()}` which also works

Comment: Yes, if we use arrow function we do not need to bind this, but in the traditional function, we need to bind this.